# Unravel strided indices

Tags: arrays, numpy, broadcast, stride

I am trying to write a routine which returns the raveled strided indices given the shape of two operands. It should take into account broadcasting and from these "raveled strided indices" it should be possible to get which values are being accessed for the two arrays (operands) if there are flattened.

Some examples which I hope explains this better:

```
shapeA = (4,3)
shapeB = (3,)
```

should output

```
strideA = [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]
strideB = [0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  2]
```

Another example:

```
shapeA = (4,1)
shapeB = (3,)
```

should output

```
strideA = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
strideB = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

My attempt (which only works on the first example):

```
def ravel_strided_indices(shapeA, shapeB):
    out_shape = np.broadcast_shapes(shapeA, shapeB)
    flatten = np.prod(out_shape)
    strideA = np.arange(flatten) % np.prod(shapeA)
    strideB = np.arange(flatten) % np.prod(shapeB)
    return strideA, strideB
```

Does there exist any convenient way of doing this in numpy (maybe something similar to `np.ravel_multi_index` or `np.indices`) ?

**EDIT**

I am looking for something that would make this operation

```
A = np.random.randn(3,1,5,2,1)
B = np.random.randn(1,4,5,1,5)

A + B
```

Equivalent with this operation:

```
indicesA, indicesB = ravel_strided_indices(A.shape, B.shape)
out_shape = np.broadcast_shapes(A.shape, B.shape)

(A.flatten()[indicesA] + B.flatten()[indicesB]).reshape(out_shape)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following can get you started.

```
import numpy as np
AA = np.random.randn(3,1,5,2,1)
BB = np.random.randn(1,4,5,1,5)
CC = AA + BB
out_shape = np.broadcast_shapes(AA.shape,BB.shape)
aidx   = np.arange(np.prod(AA.shape)).reshape(AA.shape)
bidx   = np.arange(np.prod(BB.shape)).reshape(BB.shape)
aidx_b = np.broadcast_to(aidx,CC.shape)
bidx_b = np.broadcast_to(bidx,CC.shape)
cnew   = (AA.flatten()[aidx_b.flatten()] + BB.flatten()[bidx_b.flatten()]).reshape(out_shape)
print('norm diff=',np.linalg.norm(CC-cnew))
```

Edit: the question, of course, is why you'd want to do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. The motivation behind my question is that I want to process the array on the GPU and in doing so I find it more convenient working with flattened 1d arrays. I can cache ```aidx_b``` and ```bidx_b``` so it only needs to be computed the first time we are doing the operation.